# Cassandra fails to start on Docker Toolbox external volume

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

The issue is related to running "library/Cassandra" version 3.11.2 on Docker Toolbox (docker-machine version 0.11.0) on Windows 7.

These are versions that I have to use due to constraints at my place of work, and can confirm that I have had no problems doing exactly the same thing on Docker on Mac OSX at home.

Cassandra works fine if I don't map the data directory to an external volume in the Compose file, but has the downside of causing the Virtualbox VM to fill up on a regular basis. It's fine for development, but a pain for our other systems such as Test and won't be of any use in Production.

I am aware of the constraints imposed by Docker Toolbox for Windows, especially around the use of C:\Users as mount points.

My docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  cassandra:
    privileged: true
    image: cassandra
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
      - "7001:7001"
      - "7199:7199"
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\davis_s\docker-volumes\cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
    container_name: cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=mycluster
      - CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
      - CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1
    networks:
      - smartdeploy_evo
```

When I map the data volume for Cassandra to a folder outside of the VM it stops when it gets to the following line:

```
cassandra    | INFO  [main] 2018-07-27 10:49:00,044 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
```

It does manage to create the following folders under this location (which was totally empty prior to startup):

```
commitlog
data
hints
saved_caches
```

with other subdirectories under these ones, such as data/system/Index-info.. etc.

I have left it over the weekend and it never gets past this line.

The output for "docker inspect" related to the mount point looks as follows:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/c/Users/davis_s/docker-volumes/cassandra",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/cassandra",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

I have tried the following to try and overcome this:

- Given full (recursive) Windows permissions to "Everyone" on C:\Users\davis_s
- Mapped a different Shared Folder in VirtualBox, again with full permissions for "Everyone"
- Tried running the Cassandra container with "Privileged: true"

I've seen a few other posts on SO related to Cassandra stopping at a similar point, but these look to have been solved by clearing the folder and restarting which is relevant in this case (as it started empty anyway!).

Thanks in advance...